# Downloading data from Yahoo

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I have been downloading stock information from Yahoo using this method:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s= (enter stocks here) &f= (add tags depending on what info I need)
```

This provides me with a csv file with the requested information.

What I want to do is download only the information that satisfies a certain requirement. For example I want to only download data on stocks that are worth more than $100 per share, or stocks that have lost %10 of value during a day.

Much appreciated if someone could tell me how to do this or even if there is a better method than what I am doing.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

can you try to use the YQL console. See example below.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20internet&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+in+(%22MSFT%22)+and+startDate+%3D+%222012-09-13%22+and+endDate+%3D+%222012-09-16%22%0A

Further there you have other table you can use to receive information. See yahoo.finance Tables.